# Problema con ExecutorService

Tags: java, hilos, executorservice

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que voy a realizar una cantidad grande de operaciones que se pueden realizar simultáneamente, por ello he pensado en crear hilos.

Estas operaciones darán un resultado que lo quiero almacenar en una lista para que cuando se terminen de ejecutar los hilos poder procesar esos resultados.

El problema que estoy teniendo con el código que pondré a continuación, es  que estoy haciendo pruebas con un tamaño de 320 pcs en la lista de `todosPC`, pero la lista de resultados `resultados` me está devolviendo un número inferior variable, o sea que unas ejecuciones me pone que hay 317 resultados y otras 319.

No se me ocurre que puede ser el causante de este problema, ¿alguna sugerencia?

A continuación pongo el código que tengo:

```
private static final int TELNET_SIZE = 50;
private static final long TIMEOUT_WAIT_EXECUTION = 60;
private static ExecutorService  threadPool = null;
private static List<ResTelnetDto> resultados = new ArrayList<ResTelnetDto>();

public static void main( String[] args )
{
     List<PCDto> todosPC = getAllPcs();

     int total = todosPC.size();

     //Calculamos el número de hilos a crear
     if(total > TELNET_SIZE){
          hilos = total/TELNET_SIZE ;

          if((total % TELNET_SIZE) > 0 ){
              hilos++;
          }
     }else if(total >0){
          hilos++;
     }

     threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(hilos);

     for(PCDto pc : todosPC){

         pcParciales.add(pc);
         int partialSize = pcParciales.size();

         //repartimos los pcs en cada hilo
         if (partialSize == TELNET_SIZE || counter == total) {

            //se abre el hilo para que realice las operaciones
            comprobarPCs(pcParciales);

            pcParciales.clear();
        }
     }

     threadPool.shutdown();

     threadPool.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT_WAIT_EXECUTION, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     logApp.info("Todas las tareas terminadas! resultados: " + resultados.size());
}


public static void comprobarPCs(final List<PCDto> pcParciales){

    final List<PCDto> pcs = new ArrayList<PCDto>(pcParciales);

    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 

            for(PCDto pc : pcs){                    

                boolean res = telnet(pc.getNombre(), pc.getPuertos());

                resultados.add(new ResTelnetDto(pc.getId(), ((res)?1:0)));  
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He solucionado mi problema, el problema estaba en que se estaba accediendo a la lista de resultados concurrentemente.

Para solucionarlo ha bastado con utilizar [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)):

```
private static List<ResTelnetDto> resultados = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ResTelnetDto>());
```